# Observable<List<SomeItems> from multiple retrofit requests

Tags: android, android-studio, retrofit, rx-java

I get Flowable from retrofit request. 
I need to get from multiple requests one Object like Observable> in while construction:

```
public static Observable<List<CurrencyStamp>> getStampByDay(String symbol, Date date, String... convertsSymbols){
        long count = 0;

        Observable<List<CurrencyStamp>> result = null;
        while (count < secByDay){
            Flowable<CurrencyStamp> item = CoinApi.getCompareApi().getCurrencyHistory(symbol, date.getTime() - count,
                    convertsSymbols).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());


            count += secByFiveMin;
        }


        return result;
    }
```

Which operators i need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to build off of Maximm Volgin's answer here. (Thank you)

I believe you have multiple observable streams you want to combine into a list of items. I'll break this down into two parts.

1. Combining the streams into one. This can be accomplished with the zip, merge or flatMap operators depending on order/behaviour [Zip Doc](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) [Merge Doc](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/merge.html) [FlatMap](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html).
2. Converting the data from individual items to a list. This can be accomplished with a toList()

I would also suggest not using flowables/Observables for Retrofit calls but Singles instead.

The code will end up looking something along the lines of:

Kotlin:

```
fun example(): Single<List<CurrencyStamp >> {
    val count = secByDay.div(secByFiveMin)
    return Observable
        .range(0, count)
        .flatMapSingle { curr ->
            // This should be giving you back a Single
            CoinApi.getCompareApi().getCurrencyHistory(symbol, 
                date.getTime() - curr.mul(secByFiveMin),
                convertsSymbols)
        }.toList()
}
```

Java:

```
    Single<List<CurrencyStamp>> sample() {
    val count = secByDay / secByFiveMin;
    return Observable
            .range(0, count)
            .flatMapSingle((Function<Integer, SingleSource<String>>) curr -> 
             // This should be giving you back a Single
            CoinApi.getCompareApi().getCurrencyHistory(symbol, 
                date.getTime() - (curr * secByFiveMin),
                convertsSymbols))
            .toList();
}
```

** Edit: Also you should be handling errors in a stream that can have errors (like a network call) Check out this medium article that talks about it [Error handling article](https://medium.com/mindorks/rxjava2-and-retrofit2-error-handling-on-a-single-place-8daf720d42d6)

Comment: I can't transfer this example to my case. What are parametrs in range method for me? how use this with cycle like in my case?

Comment: I updated the example to use the range how you were previously using count. Let me know if that works for you. If it doesn't can you be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: I would suggest looking to batch the requests from the server and request it all at once.

Comment: i was careless. This api have method for snapshot with intervals of time

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```java
Observable
  .range(/* */)
  .flatMap (count) -> { CoinApi
    .getCompareApi(/**/)
    .toObservable()
   }
   .toList()
```